# Why I get two cookies with one name bu different values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It is strange but if I am trying to set jwt barear token to my cookie in login method

I get result as in the picture ([linkHere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmQTx.png)).

There is 2 cookies wirh different values with the same name.

First of them is not valid and I don`t know what is a value set in this cookie.

Another one is valid token

What may be wrong?
I add cookie with this code

```
                HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("BankWeb.AspNetCore.ProductKey", authResultw.Data.Token,
   new CookieOptions
   {
       MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
       IsEssential = true
   });
```

Do i  need to remove  this cookie?

Comment: I would guess it is the "SameSite" setting that makes the difference. Cookies are not identical, if they apply to different domains!

Comment: Yes 
Thank you))